# Jinja2 - Expressions concatenating issue

Tags: flask, jinja2

I've got this variable 
`{% set img = Bicycles[Keys[i]][2] %}` which is a string
I'm trying to add it to an img html element like this

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=' {{ img }} ') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">`

My expected output when the page loads is

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='theurlhere') }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">`

But all i get is this `"/static/%20%7B%7B%20img%20%7D%7D%20"`

I'm so lost e_e

Comment: try `{{ img | safe }}`

Comment: Oh actually-- just `{{ url_for('static', filename=img) }}` should work fine-- no need to `{{ img }}` when you're already in 'jinja mode because of the surrounding `{{ }}` tags

Answer (score 0):

you need to concatenate the variable img. instead of using `{{ img }}` use `'~img~'`

This is a link to a similar question asked here

[String concatenation in Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061439/string-concatenation-in-jinja)

Comment: Need to use formatting rules, especially for code snippets - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help